# Curve to Mesh - Not all faces are not connected

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, faces

I have a Bezier curve, which has the following settings:

[image]

When converting this to a mesh, in Edit Mode, some of the faces are connected and others are not. Not sure if this is intended, but is there a way to convert it, where all the neighbouring faces are connected?

[image: Original curve]

This is the original curve

[image: Curve converted to a mesh]

Here the curve has been converted to a mesh, with two vertices raised upward. You can see that one is connected, and the one selected is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you convert the curve to a mesh,

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode
- <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices
- Hit <kbd>W</kbd> and choose "Remove Doubles"